# Approaching Studying Topology

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, self-learning

I'm writing this question to briefly inquire how to go about studying Topology based on my experience of having studied a bit of it. I have studied the first half of James Munkres' *Topology*, except for some units on the countability axioms.

A basic search shows that Topology is the studying of classifying spaces that are homeomorphic, or spaces that are identical to other under (continuous) deformations. I feel as if the the first half of the course on point-set topology was a bit of a let down in this regard. Nowhere did such issues arise; all what we did was defined various toplogical concepts and see the implications and relations between certain toplogical concepts on the toplogy defined on a space.

> My questions are:
>
> 1. How is topology pedalogically taught?
> 2. After learning point-set topology, when/how can one go about learning toplogy with the focus I mentioned above? Does one have to venture into the study of Algebraic Topology?

On the whole, I am looking for responses that explain how is the subject taught pedalogically and how should one go about studying it?

Comment: for lots of pedagogical clues: open and thoroughly read the wikipedia entries about the thing

Comment: @janmarqz It'd be great if you or someone else could briefly explain along with textbooks one can potentially use?

Comment: what about "Topology without Tears"? from Sidney A. Morris